# javascript exiting function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function MyFunction() {

  //do some work

  if (SomeCondition === true) {
     //do some work
     FunctionToCall();
  }
  //do some more work
}

function FunctionToCall() {...}
```

If ever I call the FunctionToCall(), I don't want to continue with `do some more work`. Do I need to put a return true or return false statement after the `FunctionToCall();` statement? It seems to work with both.

Thanks.

Comment: You just need to `return;` It doesn't have to be true or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, you would need to put a `return` after the call to `FunctionToCall`. By the sound of it, it doesn't matter what you return (this will return `undefined`):

```
if (SomeCondition === true) {
    //do some work
    FunctionToCall();
    return;
}
```

If you did care about the result of `FunctionToCall`, you could return the value returned from that:

```
return FunctionToCall();
```

Alternatively, you could use an `else`, and not bother with a `return` statement (this will return `undefined` too):

```
if (SomeCondition === true) {
    //do some work
    FunctionToCall();
}
else {
    //do some more work
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do a `return;`, since you are ignoring the return value of the function.

Answer (score 1):

yes you will have to put a return statement after or just before a call to next function like this

```
return FunctionToCall();
```

or

```
FunctionToCall();
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are always using `MyFunction()` in a `void`-context, use `return;`

If `FunctionToCall()` might also be invoked in a different context, I prefer putting `return true/false` in the next line.